# Gulp.js - `watch` not working on `typescript` changes, but works for `html,css` changes

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am using gulp to compile my `ts` files in to `js` file. when i change the `ts` file alone, the watch is not updating the browser. But when i change the `html` or `css` file it working fine.

I understand that, something i am missing in my `watch` property here. anyone help me to find the mistake here please?

here is my code :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpTypescript = require('gulp-typescript')
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');


var scripts = {

    in : 'app/script/ts/*.*',
    dest : 'app/script/js/'

}


gulp.task('typeScript', function () {

    return gulp.src( scripts.in )
    .pipe( gulpTypescript() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( scripts.dest ) );

});

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {

    browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    }
  })

})


gulp.task('default', ['typeScript', 'browserSync'], function () {

    gulp.watch([[scripts.in], ['typeScript']], browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch( ['app/*.html', 'app/styles/*.css'], browserSync.reload);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible [method signatures](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob-opts-tasks) for `gulp.watch` are:

```
gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)
gulp.watch(glob[, opts, cb])
```

So what you're doing here makes no sense:

```
gulp.watch([[scripts.in], ['typeScript']], browserSync.reload);
```

That means you're passing `'typeScript'` as part of the glob, when it is actually a task name.

Think about what you're trying to achieve:

1. Whenever you change a TypeScript file in `scripts.in` you want your `typeScript` task to run, so your `*.ts` files get compiled to `scripts.dest`.
2. Whenever a resulting `*.js` file in `scripts.dest` is changed you want the `browserSync.reload` callback to be executed.

So what you actually need is two different `gulp.watch` statements for those two steps of your TypeScript build process:

```
gulp.task('default', ['typeScript', 'browserSync'], function () {
  gulp.watch(scripts.in, ['typeScript']);               // 1st step
  gulp.watch(scripts.dest + '*.*', browserSync.reload); // 2nd step

  gulp.watch( ['app/*.html', 'app/styles/*.css'], browserSync.reload);
});
```